# Is there a way to change the default page index(0) in material table (reactjs)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pagination, material-ui, material-table

the default page index seems to be '0' in material table , but the api im working with starts off from page index '1' , how can i change the default page index of the table to as that of API

Comment: Yeah! That works good for pagination in material table , but i use component of material ui for pagination , I'm not able to find a way ought there to change the initial page .Thanks and sorry for note being precise!

Answer (score 2):

You can define ***initialPage*** as part of the options property which you can use to define what you need. Check the docs [here](https://material-table.com/#/docs/all-props).

[image]

```
import MaterialTable from 'material-table';

<MaterialTable
// other props

    options={{
        initialPage: 1
       }}
/>
```

I hope that works for you!

Comment: This has issues loading the remote data when the initial page is dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

```
 ***The Best way is***

    import { TablePagination} from "@material-ui/core";
    const [page, setPage] = React.useState(1);

   <TablePagination page={page - 1} onChangePage={handleChangePage}  />
   
     const handleChangePage = (event, newPage) => {
                    setPage(newPage + 1);
                };
```

Comment: Its working great for me. Thanks @Shahnad.